# What does J cm-1 stand?

Tags: optics, units, unit-conversion, experimental-technology

For an optical component, I got following number as an optical damage threshold from the company,

```
damage threshold = 10 Jcm-1,20ns, 20Hz
```

It looks like 20ns is the pulse duration and 20Hz is the repetition rate of the laser. I know 1 cm-1 = 1.98 *10^(-23) J but J cm-1 doesn't make any sense to me? How would one calculate the peak pulse power from it?
If I assume 10 J cm-1 is simply 1.98 *10^(-22) J, energy per pulse then I get the peak power to be ~ 9*10^(-14) W, which doesn't make much sense.

I should know better but I am not certain of the convention they are using.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page

> http://cvilaseroptics.com/custom/LIDT

seems to contain very similar numbers for the induced damaged threshold,
$$ 2\,{\rm J}\cdot {\rm cm}^{-2}, \quad 20\,{\rm ns}, \quad 20\,{\rm Hz}$$
Note that the power of the centimeter is $-2$, minus two. This simply means the amount of energy (two joules) deposited per unit area (squared centimeter) in one pulse (which takes 20 nanoseconds, and is repeated 20 times a second). My understanding is that the average power is $2\times 20=40$ watts in my case.

If that material really has the exponent of the centimeter $-1$, it's probably some wire and the energy has to be focused on the wire so that it is measured per unit length.

There is no conversion between joules and centimeters here.

Comment: Thank you Lubos. The material is a 2d glass. The unit being cm-2 was one of my suspicion but I wanted to double check that I am not missing some notation system industry uses.

PS. I can't believe I am getting a reply from you. I am a regular visitor of your blog, thank for actively updating it!

Answer (score 0):

In specifications of the damage threshold of optical components (laser damage threshold, LDT), "per cm" means "per cm of beam diameter", with the assumption of a beam with a circular cross section hitting the optical surface. This is related to heating of the material; with a small spot diameter, the heat can leave more easily from the spot (or cylindrical volume in the case of e.g. a lens) than with a large spot diameter, assuming the same power density (W/cm2). Hence, the maximum power handling capability of laser optics can be in W/cm if the dominant damage mechanism is due to overheating.

It doesn't make much sense to specify this for pulse energy (J/cm), though; indeed, one would use J/cm2.